# React functional component state is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am not able to update the `togglelight` state 
although changing the text state works fine.

```
export default function CardImageExample (props) {

  const [text,setext] = React.useState("Open Gate")
  const [togglelight,setogglelight] = React.useState(props.data.light)

  function change(){
    setext("Gate Opened")
    db.ref('/Door').set({mainDoor : 'opened' })
    setTimeout(function(){setext("Open Gate")}, 1300)
  }

  function ToggleLights(){
    console.log("before toggle",togglelight)

    if(togglelight)
    setogglelight(false)

    else
      setogglelight(true)

    console.log("after toggle",togglelight)
  }

  return (
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Content>
        <Button rounded style={styles.button} onPress={change} >
          <Text style={styles.text}> {text} </Text>
        </Button>

        <Text>{'\n\n'}</Text>

        <ToggleSwitch
          isOn={togglelight}
          onColor="yellow"
          offColor="grey"
          label="Lights  "
          labelStyle={styles.text}
          size="medium"
          onToggle={ToggleLights}
        />


      </Content>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have not sgared the return function because the rest of the code works fine... just the state is not updating

Comment: Do you pass an object called data with light inside as props?

Comment: Can you please also show the `return` part of your component? Thanks!

Comment: yes that i did .

Comment: how do you know if it's not working or not? the console logs you have are not going to show the correct values

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setogglelight()` with the callback parameter in order to access the previous state of `togglelight` properly.

Try as the following:

```
function ToggleLights() {
   setogglelight(prevLight => !prevLight);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

changing the state is asynchronous function

try changing your function to this

```
  async function ToggleLights(){
      console.log("before toggle",togglelight)

      if(togglelight)
          await setogglelight(false)

      else
          await setogglelight(true)

      console.log("after toggle",togglelight)
  }
```

hope this helps

Comment: a state dispatch is not an async function, nor it returns a promise, and even if it did, this wouldn't solve the issue